# How to create qt application in eclipse cdt when qt plugin not working in windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, eclipse-cdt

I've installed nokia qt plugin

```
Qt C++ Eclipse Integration
Version: 1.6.1
```

but it's not working in Eclipse MARS 2 (4.5.2).
I also installed qt 5.6.

So i need to somehow configure my cdt project to see qt libraries.
To make

```
#include <QApplication>
```

work
and also to make the project to successfully build.

How to do that?

I've tried to add C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\include to project include directories but

```
#include <QApplication>
```

not working.

I cannot work with imported Makefile project for qmake generated Makefile, because for each .o file entry it contains

```
release/EntryPoint.o: EntryPoint.cpp bios/Bios.hpp \
...
        ../../../../Qt/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtWidgets/QLabel \
        ../../../../Qt/5.6/mingw49_32/include/QtWidgets/qlabel.h \
... 100 of lines here
```

This 100 of lines won't appear without external hepl for each added cpp file in project. Importing Makefile to eclipse provides project with not working  includes.

Is there a way to make qt work with any version of eclipse?

Comment: Use Qt Creator or Visual Studio with Qt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894097/how-do-i-use-qt-in-my-visual-studio-2015-projects Eclipse is just bad and bad with Qt for no reason when we have better.

Answer (score 0):

Using cmake solves your problem with creating the projects you need.
That should not matter if you are using *nix Makefiles, nmake, visual studio or whatever.

Edit:
I just checked if it is working with CMake.
Installing Qt 5.6 mingw49 and Eclipse 4.5.2.
After creating the project with cmake 3.5.1 I imported it and it just compiles fine!
There is a problem with the Path variable but copying the exe to the bin folder of Qt is working (do not have time to check what is the problem).

Here is a starting point of cmake and Qt:

```
PROJECT(minimal)
add_definitions(-DUSE_QT)
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C://Qt//5.6//mingw49_32")

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

FILE(GLOB HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h")
FILE(GLOB CPP_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp")
FILE(GLOB UI_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.ui")
FILE(GLOB RC_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.qrc")


QT5_ADD_RESOURCES(ENTITY_DEBUGGER_RC_SRCS ${RC_FILES} )

QT5_WRAP_UI( ENTITY_DEBUGGER_UI_HDRS ${UI_FILES})

ADD_EXECUTABLE( minimal 
            ${CPP_FILES}
            ${ENTITY_DEBUGGER_RC_SRCS} 
            ${ENTITY_DEBUGGER_UI_HDRS} 
            ${HEADER_FILES} 
            )

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(minimal PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX _d)


qt5_use_modules(minimal Widgets Core)


INSTALL(TARGETS minimal
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  )
```

PS: I strongly agree that Eclipse is not the best IDE.
There are some other free IDEs (VS, QtCreator, Sublime, Codeblocks, ...)