# How can I display my C++ Program output on the GUI Ouput Window instead of the cmd console in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I tried searching through the internet, but couldn't find any answer.

The visual studio opens up a cmd prompt when I run my program and the output's are shown there. Is there a way to not have a cmd window, but have this on some Windows GUI dialog box?

Please help. I need to sleep now!

EDIT: Ok, i think I didn't ask the question better. I still want a console application, but I just want my debug run outputs in a text-type window (like the output window in visual studio) rather than a command console. e.g. 'http://cpp.sh/' gives you the output in a text-window rather than create a console.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to make a forms application?

To achieve this, there are different approaches:
One would be to rely on the .NET framework and use the windows runtime extensions. That however would make you lose portability, and makes C++ feel and behave like a whole other language altogether.

The other, in my opinion better approach would be to use something like [QT](https://www.qt.io/). QT is quite well known and used to make applications on many different platforms. Besides forms it also offers a lot of other nice functionality. Just take a look at its documentation.

The installer also includes its own IDE, QT Creator, but if you prefer to use Visual Studio instead, [here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894097/how-do-i-use-qt-in-my-visual-studio-2015-projects). Then, when creating a new project, select a QT application. It should automatically have a form. You can then open the .ui file to change the GUI to your needs.