# Install qt-vs-addin-msvc2015-2.0.0-beta in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, qt-vs-addin

I want to install the Qt addin for Visual Studio 2015.

From the Qt site I've downloaded the file qt-vs-addin-msvc2015-2.0.0-beta, that's a zip file, but when I unzip it I've a bunch of files and folders and I don't know how to install it.

How can I install this extension?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894097/how-do-i-use-qt-in-my-visual-studio-2015-projects

Comment: I don't find any suggestion in order to install the plugin. I've already the latest version of Qt and I can use it with CMake if the target is VS2015. But I need to create new project without cmake now, so I need the plugin installed, and this is the version compatible with VS2015, but it's not a VSIX, it's a ,zip

Comment: It should be vsix and installed as VS extension. Could you give a link?

Comment: Ok It's windows edge that renames the file extension....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you got the zip file, you can download the vsix file from [here](http://download.qt.io/development_releases/vsaddin/), which can be directly installed in VS as an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer (I'm using v11) and, according to the comments above, the MS Edge browser, rename .vsix files to .zip files when they are downloaded from the qt.io website.  This is especially confusing because .vsix files are, in fact, valid .zip files; however, extracting their contents into a folder doesn't provide the user with any method of installing them.

Change the extension on the files from .zip to .vsix and double-click the resulting icon.  That should launch the vsix installer.