# TWAIN Sample Data Source

Tags: twain

I downloaded the code of TWAIN sample Data Source : twainds.source.2.1.3 and opened visual_studio TWAINDS_VS2008.sln.
When I start debugging, it shows 2 Errors. These are

> "error PRJ0019: A tool returned an error code from "Rcc'ing c:...\TWAIN\TWAIN\twainds.source.2.1.3\Twain_DS_sample01\src\qtresources.qrc..."   TWAINDS_Sample File

&

> "error BK1506 : cannot open file '.\Debug32\CommonTWAIN.sbr': No such file or directory"   BSCMAKE File

I checked this code on Windows 7 64 bit as well as on Windows 10 64 bit and got the same errors. I don’t know what to do to compile the TWAIN Sample Data Source?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the TWAIN DS uses QT. You have two options:

1) [How do i use Qt in my Visual Studio 2015 projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894097/how-do-i-use-qt-in-my-visual-studio-2015-projects) --> use QT in your project 
OR
2) Remove all QT files from source header and resource sections and build.
With the 2nd option you probably will not be able to use the sample DS directly. you may have to replace them with your Win32 code which should be quite easy.

Please revert back in case of any discrepancies or queries.